# When I print PokemonData, it is coming undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get a pokemon list from the given URL but I am getting undefined while printing **pokemonData**. However, I can get the required data while printing data. I am new to this and what I understand is using setPokemonData(data) sets the value of pokemon. Can anybody help explaining me what am I doing wrong over here?

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import noImage from "../img/no-image-available.jpg";

import "../App.css";

export default function PokemonList() {
  const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);
  let li = null;
  let img = null;

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get("https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/");
        setPokemonData(data.results.map((p) => p));
        console.log(data.results);
        console.log(pokemonData);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    }
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    // <div>
    //   {pokemonData.map((p) => (
    //     <div key={p}>{p}</div>
    //   ))}
    // </div>
    null
  );
}
```

Comment: Firstly, you should always give your states a default value, i.e. `const [pokemonData, setPokemonData] = useState([]);`. Secondly, state changes in react are asynchronous, so the change won't show if you console.log right after changing it. There's a million posts and articles and such covering that topic

Comment: @Jayce444 Thankyou for the help.